# Limiting the size of vbstring to 10240 bytes in VB6

Tags: vb6

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to declare variable containing character limiting to 1000 bytes in vb6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286476/how-to-declare-variable-containing-character-limiting-to-1000-bytes-in-vb6)
>   [“Object variable or With block variable not set” runtime error in VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206526/object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set-runtime-error-in-vb6)

**Exact duplicate** of askers own question [How to declare variable containing character limiting to 1000 bytes in vb6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286476/how-to-declare-variable-containing-character-limiting-to-1000-bytes-in-vb6)

How to declarare the size of string variable as 10240 butes in VB6?

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked earlier? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286476/how-to-declare-variable-containing-character-limiting-to-1000-bytes-in-vb6

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Dim s As String * 5120 
' Gives 10240 bytes, as pointed out by KristoferA
```

This will ensure the string is ALWAYS 5120 characters, if there are less in there, it will be padded with spaces. e.g.

```
Dim s As String * 10
s = "Hello"
Debug.Print "[" & s & "]"
```

gives

```
[Hello     ]
```

Answer (score 1):

10240 bytes* or characters*?

```
Dim strFoo As String * 5120 // 10240 bytes  
Dim strFoo As String * 10240 // 10240 characters
```

(* = VB6 strings are unicode, so each character in a string takes 2 bytes)

Comment: This gives me a compiler error, what am I missing?

Comment: A star. Dim strFoo As String*5120

Comment: Heh, MarkJ is right, my memory failed me... Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax for a fixed-length string of 5120 characters, which is 10240 bytes. The value will always have 5120 characters - trailing spaces will be added, or excess characters truncated. [VB6 strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212271(office.10).aspx) are [Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) (UTF-16) and therefore each character has 2 bytes.

```
Dim s As String * 5120  ' 5120 characters, 10240 bytes
```

It's not clear whether you are dealing with binary data rather than text. The [Byte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220031.aspx) data type is better for binary data.

```
Dim byt(10240) as Byte  ' an array of 10240 bytes
```